# Aiogram Webhook start_webhook() not working in async

Tags: python, asynchronous, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

The code is completely copied from the documentation.
https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example.html
All requests go sequentially, checked with asyncio.sleep()

Operating System:
Python Version: 3.10.2
aiogram version: 2.25.1
aiohttp version: 3.8.4

I also checked with a request to the server, the situation is the same, everything goes in turn